# Is there any combination of memory mitigations COOP doesn't bypass?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I recently seen a paper where COOP exploit dev was used to bypass DEP+ASLR+CET+CFG+SEHOP. JIT attack surfaces like v8 seem to have even less hardening. Is there a form of exploitable memory corruption that COOP doesn't work on?